# Select from selection based on attribute table in ArcGIS or arcpy

Tags: selection, arcgis

I selected polygons which are less than 313 m<sup>2</sup>, and from that selection I need to select the ones that are completely within some other polygon. So, both selections are on the same shapefile.

I tried selection by attribute and by location which seems to respond.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to script this in Python, or just do it in ArcMap? Since you say you used Select by Attribute/Location and that worked, what are you having problems with?

Comment: The initial issue was to merge polygons that have area smaller than 1250 m2 to the larger polygons which surround them, based on the boundary sharing. For instance, the smaller polygon shares more boundary to the ‘A’ polygon than the ‘B’ polygon (which are both the neighbors of the small polygon) then it should be merged to the polygon which shares the boundary the most, which is ‘A’ in this case.

Comment: Coming from this point of view, I selected polygons which are smaller than 1250 m2 and the next step is to find out the boundary sharing of neighboring polygons and based on that merge smaller polygons to them. It is like “Rich gets richer, and poor gets pooper.” I think, initially I might be on the wrong track, which led to the wrong question I asked, initially. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I am doing this in ArcMap first, and once I got the satisfying results I will try to do the procedure in Python.

Comment: FYI, for future questions [GIS.SE](gis.stackexchange.com) may be a better place to ask (it's GIS specific and therefore will get a faster response than GIS questions on StackOverflow, especially when it's more about process than failing code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find small polygons, you want to use [Select by Attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) on the `Shape.Area` field.

Based on your comments and overall project goal, I suggest using [Polygon Neighbors](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm) instead of trying to do everything with just Select tools.

> The tool analyzes polygon contiguity, summarizing the
>
> - Area of overlaps (overlapping neighbors—optional)
> - The length of coincident edges (edge neighbors)
> - The number of times boundaries cross or touch at a point (node neighbors)
>
> between source polygons and neighbor polygons. The summary information is written to an output table. A source polygon may have one or more neighbor polygons; a neighbor polygon is spatially related with the source polygon in at least one of the above ways.

Since it generates a separate table, the arcpy script would need to be moderately more complex (reading that table and making some decisions based on the content), but it's absolutely a simpler approach when going through the procedure manually in ArcMap.